# is_land in basemap (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I've been trying to mask land with `.is_land` from `mpl_toolkits.basemap`.

When running following code:

`map = Basemap(llcrnrlon = 7.298914095230308, llcrnrlat = 58.98235690451632, 
               urcrnrlon = 12.27072348324015, urcrnrlat = 
               57.92306182768044,projection='cyl', resolution='f')`

`value = map.is_land(11.61168822665539, 57.86868795294363)`

`print(value)`  returns False

but when not specifying a region

`map = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='f')`

`value = map.is_land(11.61168822665539, 57.86868795294363)`

`print(value)`  returns True

Which I can't figure out why.

I really do need to specify region or else the code will be 5-6 times slower to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apply `is_land` incorrectly. According to http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html?highlight=is_land#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.is_land
`is_land` returns True if the given x,y point (in projection coordinates) is over land, False otherwise. The definition of land is based upon the
GSHHS coastline polygons associated with the class instance. Points
 over lakes inside land regions are not counted as land points.

It means you have to convert your lat-lon coordinate to x,y of projection and then run `is_land`. Like here:

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon = 7.298914095230308, llcrnrlat = 58.98235690451632, 
               urcrnrlon = 12.27072348324015, urcrnrlat = 
               57.92306182768044,projection='cyl', resolution='f')

lon, lat = 11.61168822665539, 57.86868795294363) # test coords
xpt, ypt = map( lon, lat ) # convert to projection map
value = map.is_land(xpt, ypt) # test is_land
```

Comment: With `projection='cyl'`,  it is Plate Carree' projection. So that, you can use lat, long in degrees in `map.is_land()`. In other words,  `xpt, ypt = map( lon, lat )` is not necessary in this case.